# mongoose --how to find the object where its field "name" does not contain number

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In the mongodb model clothes, there is a collection called name.

I want to find and list all the product where its name does not contain 2016.

For example the name = " just jeans black jacket 2016"   or "west jeans back pants"

my code is :

```
clothes.find()
       .and([{name: "black"},{name: {$ne: '2016'}}])
```

it doesn't work.

I was thinking to use mongoose aggregation,but have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
clothes.find({ name: { $not: /2016/ } })
```

If you need name with "black" and without "2016" do:

```
clothes.find({ $and: [{ name: /black/i }, { name: { $not: /2016/ } }] })
```